# Copy from a container with different integral element type

Tags: c++

I want to cast a `vector` of `long long` to a `vector` of `int` (or vice versa), so I would to something like

```
std::vector<long long> a{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> b;
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b));
```

It works, but I wonder if it's safe to copy from a container with different integral element type (e.g. undefined behavior). I checked [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) but it says nothing about it. If it's not safe, then what's the best way to do something like this?
Do I have to do

```
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), [](int x) { return x; });
```

instead?

Comment: It's not undefined behaviour. If your original data doesn't fit in the new type however it'll be truncated

Comment: `std::vector<long long> a{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> b(a.begin(), a.end());` should be better.

Comment: If elements of type `long long` can't be represented by an `int`, then the result of converting to `int` is implementation-defined before C++20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no undefined behavior here. This line:

```
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b));
```

is more or less equivalent to this:

```
for (auto value : a) {
    b.push_back(value);
}
```

where `value` is a `long long` and `b.push_back` takes an `int`. This just performs an [integral conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). In particular:

> If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type.

If the source integer is too large, then what happens is implementation-defined (not undefined) pre-C++20, and well-defined (modulo or "truncation") in C++20.

Your example with `std::transform` also does more or less the same thing.

Note that you may want to `reserve` space in `b` before copying (`b.reserve(a.size())`), or just initialize `b` directly with `a` (`std::vector<int> b(a.begin(), a.end())`).

Answer (score 2):

`copy` merely copies elements. The `backinserter` makes room for more elemements, and because `b` is a vector of `int`s it will insert `int`s at the back of `b`. No issue with any of that. Your usage of copy is as safe as assigning single elements is:

```
long long a = 42;
int b = a;
```

When the value of `a` is too long to fit into `int` it will be truncated.

See also the possible implementation of `std::copy` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy, which boils down to assigning elements of one range to another (via `*d_first = *first;`).